# TypeScript typing for Array spread as Object

Tags: typescript

I'm spreading an Array into an object to extend some properties... the problem I'm encountering is basically as follows:

```
const arr = [1, 2]
const obj = {...arr};

// TypeScript fails to catch this error
obj.forEach(v => console.log(v))
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gRgDQwEwC6AUKJLCAEYBWqMA3gHROIIC+A3EUQPTcwAqATwAOAUwDKwBAEthsAGZxpAGwgwoIGMDhRgAC3V7pa0UhAIilKg3nmAonH0AKAG6oAfFvAQQy0Q2UQAHNXAEpQohgYIA)

The resulting `obj` will contain the keys of the array e.g. '0', '1', and any other enumerable properties of the array (for example `RegExp.prototype.exec` array would have additional enumerable properties `index` and `input`)

TypeScript will still see the `obj` Object as an Array, and intellisense/auto-complete will think that all of the Array methods such as `forEach` are still available. Is there any way to make this typesafe?

A real-world use case:

```js
export const matchAll = (re: RegExp, str: string): Array<any> => {
  const matches = [];
  let match: RegExpExecArray | null;
  let lastIndex = 0;
  while ((match = re.exec(str))) {
    matches.push({...match, lastIndex});
    lastIndex = re.lastIndex;
  }
  
  // the implicit type of `matches` items will have a lot of 
  // methods that are not accessible
  return matches;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does precising the type may be a solution in your case ?

Like this :
[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gRgDQwEwC6AUKJLCAEYBWMAXDAPLUCmwsaA3gHQ+IIC+AbiJEA9KJgAVAJ4AHZgGVgCAJazYAMzgqANhBhQQMYHCjAAFgfMr9zJCARiJlKlyIwYQA)

```js
const arr = [1, 2];
const obj : Object = {...arr};
```

Answer (score 0):

Spreading will only clone properties that don't exist on the prototype. Unfortunately, TypeScript does not see it this way.

I suggest annotating `obj` for what it really is.

```
const obj: Record<number, number> = { ...arr };
```

You can also make the conversion explicit by abstracting it to a function.

```
function toObject<T>(arr: T[]): Record<number, T> {
    return { ...arr };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in TypeScript. Destructured array assigned to object should not be assignable to an array. It is reported here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34780